# Check my index.php please

Tags: php

I everybody, ive coded a script recently seems to be good but when i go to my page on on localhost, ive an error like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /srv/http/index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/http/index.php on line 11

```js
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db_hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'mypass';
$db_database = 'my database name';


    $connect = mysql_connect("$db_hostname","$db_username","$db_password");

    if (!$connect)
        {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    mysql_select_db($db_database) or die ("could not find db");



    $output ='';



    if (isset ($_POST['search'])){

    $search = $_POST['search'];
    }


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email LIKE '%".$search."%'" ) or die("could not search");

    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    
        if($count == 0){

        $output = 'There was no search results !';
        }

    
    else{

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $fname = $row['search];
        $output .='<div> '.$fname.'</div>';
        }

        }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Lookup</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="search" name="search">
<input type="submit" value=">>"/>

</form>



<?php

print("$output"); 

?>

  </body>
</html>
```

[And this is what the page return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsTme.png)

Comment: and the error is?????????????????

Comment: .. apart from writing new code using mysql_*

Comment: *ive an error* is an absolutely useless problem description. When you get the error, there's an error message that comes with it. It's right on the screen in front of you. There is **zero** excuse for you not to include it in your question here. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**. You should be making it as easy as possible for us to do so by giving us the relevant information that is **right in front of you**.

Comment: Yeah its true but: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); dont show nothin ive just an 500 internal error

Comment: Then at least put a screenshot in your question so we can see that

Comment: At first look you don't have balanced curly braces. So error 500 probably stands for parse error. Also `$fname = $row['search];` should be `$fname = $row['search'];`.

Comment: its true this is my error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /srv/http/index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/http/index.php on line 11

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a wild guess and say that you are using PHP 7 and I'll also assume you haven't read the actual documentation for the function it is telling you doesn't exist.

Let's read the docs shall we - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

> Warning: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Heed that advice and keep it close to your soul. While you are there, learn about parameterization and why it is vital before someone deletes all your data.

Comment: that comment made my day

Comment: Instead of answers you should vote to close this as a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I have already voted :-)